# FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, pytest, unable to get 100% coverage, it doesn't properly collected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I'm trying to build `FastAPI` application fully covered with test using `python 3.9`
For this purpose I've chosen stack:
FastAPI, uvicorn, SQLAlchemy, asyncpg, pytest (+ async, cov plugins), coverage and httpx AsyncClient

Here is my minimal [requirements.txt](https://github.com/iliadmitriev/fastapi-sqlalchemy-pytest/blob/master/requirements.txt)

All tests run smoothly and I get the expected results.
But I've faced the problem, coverage doesn't properly collected. It breaks after a first `await` keyword, when coroutine returns control back to the event loop

Here is a minimal set on how to reproduce this behavior ([it's also available on a GitHub](https://github.com/iliadmitriev/fastapi-sqlalchemy-pytest)).

Appliaction code `main.py`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from starlette.requests import Request

app = FastAPI()
DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite+aiosqlite://?cache=shared'


@app.on_event('startup')
async def startup_event():
    engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, future=True)
    app.state.session = AsyncSession(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
    app.state.engine = engine


@app.on_event('shutdown')
async def shutdown_event():
    await app.state.session.close()


@app.get('/', name="home")
async def get_home(request: Request):
    res = await request.app.state.session.execute(sa.text('SELECT 1'))
    # after this line coverage breaks
    row = res.first()
    assert str(row[0]) == '1'
    return {"message": "OK"}
```

test setup `conftest.py` looks like this:

```py
import asyncio

import pytest
from asgi_lifespan import LifespanManager
from httpx import AsyncClient


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
async def get_app():
    from main import app
    async with LifespanManager(app):
        yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
async def get_client(get_app):
    async with AsyncClient(app=get_app, base_url="http://testserver") as client:
        yield client


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

test is simple as it is (just check status code is 200) `test_main.py`:

```py
import pytest
from starlette import status


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_view_health_check_200_ok(get_client):
    res = await get_client.get('/')
    assert res.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

```sh
pytest -vv --cov=. --cov-report term-missing --cov-report html
```

As a result coverage I get:

```
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------
conftest.py       18      0   100%
main.py           20      3    85%   26-28
test_main.py       6      0   100%
--------------------------------------------
TOTAL             44      3    93%
```

[image]

1. Example code above uses `aiosqlite` instead of `asyncpg` but coverage failure also reproduces persistently
2. I've concluded this problem is with `SQLAlchemy`, because this example with `asyncpg` without using the `SQLAlchemy` works like charm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's an issue with SQLAlchemy 1.4 in coveragepy: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1082, https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1012

you can try with `--concurrency==greenlet` option

Comment: I owe you one! It worked!

Answer (score 6):

That is what helped me:

You can add coverage concurrency `greenlet` settings into your configs `setup.cfg` or `.coveragerc` file:

```
[coverage:run]
branch = True
concurrency =
    greenlet
    thread
```